# SQLAlchemy complex many to many with abstractions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

We have this pattern in our very complex database which essentially boils down to a directed graph with metadata on each edge. We're solving it, but I'm sure there is a "better" solution. I'm going to attempt to describe the situation using an example.

The example is one in which we're cataloging defects on a few top level object types. Those top level object types are Fruits, Cars and People. A defect is also a top level object type, but comes in two flavors: Aesthetic Defect and Structural Defect.

So for instance a Car may have both an AestheticDefect and a StructuralDefect. Importantly, that same StructuralDefect may be assigned to both a Car and a Fruit.

All top level objects in the graph have a globally unique id, which is mapped to a type. We refer to the top level representation as an "entity".

Square brackets indicate primary key of table

**Entity Types** -> (no orm object)

- [entity_type_id] - smallint
- entity_type - string

**Entities** -> entity_type_map

- [entity_id] - bigint
- entity_type_id - smallint

The objects are represented as such:

**Fruits** -> FruitsModel

- [id] (references Entities(entity_id)) - bigint
- other columns

**Cars** -> CarsModel

- [id] (references Entities(entity_id)) - bigint
- other columns

**People** -> PeopleModel

- [id] (references Entities(entity_id)) - bigint
- other columns

Defects are represented similarly:

**Aesthetic Defect** -> AesDefectModel (inherits from BaseDefectModel)

- [id] (references Entities(entity_id)) - bigint
- other columns

**Structural Defect** -> StructDefectModel (inherits from BaseDefectModel)

- [id] (references Entities(entity_id)) - bigint
- other columns

Defects are mapped to entities as such:

**Defect Entity Map** -> DefectEntityMap

- [defect_id] (references Entities(entity_id)) - bigint
- [entity_id] (references Entities(entity_id)) - bigint

What I'd like to be able to do is say:

```
class FruitsModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Fruits"

    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey("Entities.entity_id"))
    # other cols, etc

    def print_defects(self):
        defects = self.defects
        for d in defects:
            print d

    defects = db.relationship # <--- What goes here ??
```

To get that list of defects given a Fruit I'm currently. executing a query per defect type, then concatenating the two lists in the python.

What is the right way to make relationships that'll give me all defects as either their base class (BaseDefectModel) or as a list containing mixed types (AesDefectModel and StructDefectModel)? If not a relationship, could I do this with a single query?

For the record, SQLAlchemy is more complex than most machine learning I've done.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be using polymorphic inheritance, which I just now came to understand.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/inheritance.html